# What's the basis for "דברה התורה כלשון בני"א" (Torah used common language)?

Tags: language, parshanut-theory, hermeneutics

The Sages used the "דברה התורה כלשון בני אדם" excuse (acc. to [the WIKI page](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D)) in two ways - in the Gemmorah to resolve [the problem of] repeating languages in the Torah (like עלה נעלה or פדה תפדה) and the Rishonim used it to explain why G-d is depicted in the Torah as corporeal.

What is the basis for this statement - is it speculation (סברא) or is it stated anywhere in the writings or learned through the 13 Middos?

Comment: Since this is a method of exegesis in itself (a disputed one too) I don't think it would be learned from 13 midot - on the contrary maybe it would more comparable to the way the 13 midot were derived from verses

Comment: the entire torah was given to moshe with its explanations-- including this

Comment: כלשון בני אדם..